# How does Gintoki's wooden sword get fixed again after getting broken so many times?

Tags: gintama

We've seen Gintoki's sword being broken multiple times and the sword is made of woord, a special kind of wood.

So how does it return back to normal again and again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's revealed in the series how his sword is "fixed":

> "Whenever one breaks or is stolen, Gin replaces it by purchasing it through a TV shopping program, asking them to inscribe "Lake Toya" on it prior to delivery" ([Source: Gintama Wiki](http://gintama.wikia.com/wiki/Gintoki%27s_Bokut%C5%8D)).

Scene where the process described above is shown (spoiler alert): [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dlS5sXceP20)